# AutoBinding CefSharp.BindObjectAsync in IRenderProcessMessageHandler:OnContextCreated

Tags: javascript, c#, promise, cefsharp

using CEFSharp i try to autoinject a bound Object in the `IRenderProcessMessageHandler:OnContextCreated` Method but i guess there is a `await` missing:

```
_chromeProxy = new ChromeProxy();
chromiumWebBrowser1.RenderProcessMessageHandler = new RenderProcessMessageHandler();
chromiumWebBrowser1.JavascriptObjectRepository.ObjectBoundInJavascript += (mysender, mye) =>
    {
       var name = mye.ObjectName;
       Console.WriteLine($"Object {mye.ObjectName} was bound successfully."); //Gets triggered
    };
chromiumWebBrowser1.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("App", new ChromeProxy(),  true);
```

and the `OnContextCreated` Method:

```
public void OnContextCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
        {
            // Does bind but too late ( no await )
            const string script = "CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('App');";
            frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script); 

            // ERR: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
            // const string script = "await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('App');";
            // frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);          
        }
```

Is it possible to register the bound Object with this approach and if, how could i await the result of the binding before Javascript on the page gets executed?

Comment: If ObjectBoundInJavascript was triggered then your object was bound.  You don't have to call await unless you need to execute some functions on your object.  You can use an iife if you need to call await then execute JavaScript, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/JavaScript-Binding-API#cefsharpbindobjectasyncsettings-objectname for some examples of an iife. Or use PostMessage if you just need simple message passing https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @amaitland i got it working:

the key was to use `EvaluateScriptAsync` instead of `ExecuteJavaScriptAsync` with the following iife

```
frame.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"(async function() {await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('App');})();");
```